# StackExchange "my sites" filter for drop down

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab showing only “my sites” in the StackExchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69047/tab-showing-only-my-sites-in-the-stackexchange-global-inbox)

It would be very useful to have a "my sites" filter on the StackExchange drop down (located on the top left) which filters the "all sites" list to show only the sites that you created an account on.

It could sort them based on your reputation on each site.

Rather than showing a description of what the site is about (you already know this, since you joined the site), it could show other data. I'm not sure what would be the best to show, but here are some ideas:

- Reputation/badge count
- Unread status (like the mail icon)
- My question/answer count
- Last visit time (possibly use this for sorting instead)

Comment: I came here to request this exact feature, just integrated into the StackExchange site rather than the drop down, though in the drop down does make a lot of sense.  I think the sorting should be stable though -- I use positional memory to remember things like list orders.

Comment: I second that. Moving between sites is too difficult now, with the amount of sites there are and the random order they are listed in. 
Had they been in non-dropdown list I could have atleast used a ctrl+f to quickly find the link to the site I want to go to.