# Stack exchange sites-list pop-up ORDER?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange-button, stack-exchange

There is a new "Stack Exchange" button in the top left of all the sites that lists Hot questions, Sites, and Inbox.

I really love this. But there is one annoying part.

I use the sites list to jump from site to site more than any other method of getting from one SE to another.

However they are NOT ordered by anything (or so it appears), thus ordered randomly, thus every time I want to jump to a particular site I have to search for it in the list because I don't know if it will be on the bottom, top, or middle this time.

I think ordering alphabetically would be best but really anything consistent would be great.

Comment: Sounds like [this feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66348/stackexchange-my-sites-filter-for-drop-down) that I requested would help even more, since you would only see the sites you are interested in.

Comment: I agree, that would help a lot

Comment: I would like the list to be ordered descending by the number of Questions I asked in those sites.

Comment: I agree this is really annoying when trying to find specific sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dropdown is now ambiently sorted by your rep level on each site, so you do in effect have a list of sites where you participate at the top.

[image]

You must have a minimum of **200 rep** on any given site to have it appear in anything other than random order, though.

Comment: I don't think the 200 thing is still true. Sites where I have less than 200 rep appear in rep order and above all the sites where I have no account

Answer (score 1):

This list is now sorted by reputation first, and then alphabetically to make it easier to find the site you are looking for.

[Global site drop-down in the top left should be sorted alphabetically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188910/global-site-drop-down-in-the-top-left-should-be-sorted-alphabetically)