# Global site drop-down in the top left should be sorted alphabetically

Tags: discussion, status-completed, global-inbox, sorting

The global site list is sorted by reputation first, and then randomly. This was to encourage discovery of new sites.

This list should be sorted by reputation first, and then alphabetically to make it easier to find the site you are looking for.

Comment: Poor Writers.SE, they'll never get random visitors again.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: This is referring to the "all sites" section of the Stack Exchange drop-down in the top bar.

Comment: Ah, thank you @animuson. I missed the global-inbox tag...

Answer (score 1):

This list is now sorted by reputation first, and then alphabetically to make it easier to find the site you are looking for.