# Tab showing only "my sites" in the StackExchange global inbox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, global-inbox

Hello,

I was thinking that I would like a new tab in the StackExchange global inbox that would:

- Show a list of sites for which I have an associated account.
- Highlight the sites for which I have pending notifications.

My idea is that, right now, it is somewhat painful to see only the sites for which you have an associated account, and after that you must visit all of them in order to see for which ones you have recent activity.

Here is a quick mockup of what I was thinking about:[image: New tab in the StackExchange global inbox]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We now **sort the gen-u-wine sites list by the amount of reputation you have on each site.**

[image]

You must have a minimum of **200 rep** on any given site to have it appear in anything other than random order, though.

Comment: Well, that works too.

Comment: OK, good. It would be useful to have similar functionality on  StackExchange.com as well. I have posted a feature-request for a similar thing regarding StackExchange.com [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78796/filter-on-my-accounts-in-stackexchange-com).

Comment: Is there a reason for this 200 rep treshold? For new users like myself there now is no way to quickly go to a site I'm a member of because the list is so long. Can't the sites I subscribe to just be at the top in random order?

Comment: @Tinco: Seconded. I was just about to post a bug report on this not working before I noticed the rep requirement.

Comment: @tinco because you get 101 rep minimum on all sites when you pass 200 on a single site we don't think users are serious about any given site until they pass the 200 rep threshold.

Comment: Is there a reason for the random sorting for the remainder sites? Why not alphabetical? I for one find it frustrating to scan a random list for the particular item I am looking for.

Comment: @JeffAtwood As if your opinion matters... (wink wink) but I too fail to see value in not providing a prioritized list until 200 rep. I became serious about SO the moment I signed-in with my Google account, which admittedly was months after first using SO.  It took a while to get to 200 and it's annoying that I can't just hop from SO, to Meta.SO, and OnStartups in a more straightforward fashion.  To me it's the same as if the pages load slowly... I'm more likely to leave.

Comment: Here is another "vote" for lowering the threshold for sorting or for specifically including a my sites tab. Even for new (that's me) or casual users, it seems very useful to switch between sites of interest, especially now that there are so many different Stack Exchange sites. If there is some concern about providing the tab for all users, perhaps a very low threshold, such as 15 rep is the way to go. After all you don't get to be very involved (especially vote) until you reach 15.