# Dropdown with my active accounts

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, linked-accounts, navigation

Can users have a dropdown (something like the Stack Exchange dropdown) to quickly go to websites they have **active accounts** with?

E.g. I have accounts with Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, Gaming Stack Exchange, Photography Stack Exchange and some more, although I find myself not visiting the latter (Gaming and Photography) quite often 'cause it's not easy to remember all the URLs and too much of a hassle to go through `user profile > accounts`. I suspect that having a quick access dropdown would increase the traffic to some of the websites still in beta.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69047/tab-showing-only-my-sites-in-the-stackexchange-global-inbox

Answer (score 5):

The dropdown is now ambiently sorted by your rep level on each site, so you do in effect have a list of sites where you participate at the top.

[image]

You must have a minimum of **200 rep** on any given site to have it appear in anything other than random order, though.

Comment: The dropdown does not really sort by rep... I have actually Drupal Answers, Bycicles and Role Playing games over Code Review or Programmers, and I'm not even signed up to the former three. Did you drop that feature or it's just not working?

Comment: @alea you must have +200 rep minimum on the relevant sites for the sort to happen. Any sites where you have < 200 rep will show in random order.

Answer (score 1):

This already exists. You can use the menu you mentioned in the top left corner of every site — common name: StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ — to get access. Detailed instructions: click the Stack Exchange logo to make the menu appear, then select "all sites." As the name implies, this brings up a list of every SE site.

For completeness, I'll point out that it's not customized to display only sites you have an account on, but you didn't ask for that, so... `[status-completed]`.

Comment: Isn't asking for **my active accounts** and mentioning `user profile > accounts` asking for customization to show just the sites you have an account on?  Pretty sure this is a dupe, hrm.

Comment: @rchern, I see how it could be read that way, but I feel like the OP would have said "only" if he meant "only."

Comment: demand, I think it's more obvious what rchern said, if the OP wanted a list of all sites, why would he have mentioned user accounts at all.

Comment: @Jon, good point.

Comment: Thanks. I got that. And like rchern and Jonathan have clarified already, it'd be nice to have the list shown only for the active accounts probably sorted in the order of most frequently visited ones and button which would toggle all sites and active accounts. See how you like it...thanks again.