# Sort StackExchange dropdown list of sites with 100 reputation as the threshold

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69047/130260) and [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69047/tab-showing-only-my-sites-in-the-stackexchange-global-inbox/78214#78214) indicate that the StackExchange all-site-list dropdown at the top of the screen is sorted by reputation, but that sites for which the user has less than 200 reputation are randomly listed.

It would be really handy if the threshold was 100 reputation instead. I'm not sure exactly what triggers getting 100 free reputation at a new registration. But if I register for a site then it's because I want to read it, even if I can't currently contribute, and it's mildly frustrating to have to hunt for the site in the list.

Comment: 100 bonus reputation is awarded for associating an account with a Stack Exchange account that has at least 200 reputation of its own, to answer your curiosity.

Comment: I assumed it was something like that, but it'd be nice if it were enough to get the sorting. :-)